# How to remove the save confirmation prompt?

Tags: interface

New Blender user here. I have been trying to remove the confirmation prompts when saving for more than half an hour and it is driving me mad.

What I want is to simply have Blender save the file without raising a fuss or anything when I press Ctrl+S. When I click on "Save" in the "File" menu in the top-left bar, it does that, but when I press the button combination, the confirmation prompt rears its ugly self.

I opened the "User Preferences" window and unchecked all the "Check Existing" boxes related to all the Save commands in the Window sub-category. At best, Ctrl+S brings up the "Save As" window and demands the file's destination path. At worst, it does absolutely nothing whatsoever.

Is there actually a **simple** way to disable this prompt?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw the linked potential duplicate question, and no, adding a Python script (with no explanantion whatsoever as to how we are supposed to do that) is not what I consider to be "simple". 
The other answer looks interesting but it doesn't explain at all how we are supposed to "create our operator with the file path set".

Comment: Well then to answer you original question directly: No, there is no **simple** way to disable that at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. I should have expected that from Blender, to be honest.

Anyway, in that case, how can I "create my operator with the file path set" as suggested in the linked question? That seems to be the least complicated solution.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUkofDrGd9o) or [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161/adding-operator-to-the-toolshelf) can help

Comment: Urgh, so it actually involves fiddling with scripts...

Thanks a lot for you answer!